# No result for PATH:"/" in Alfresco Node Browser

Tags: lucene, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco Community v6.0.7.
When I try to query the default path by searching just PATH:"/" in the Node Browser of Alfresco Share, I get No results and 07100085 is displayed at the Name column in the grid below.[image]

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this issue and where do we declare the app:company_home property?

Comment: I guess your solr search is not working. You should find more in the tomcat log.

Comment: depending on the programing language it is not required to search for the company_home node. e.g. in JS it is already available as [root scope object](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. I tried running Solr search services using following command

```
./solr/bin/solr start -a "-Dcreate.alfresco.defaults=alfresco,archive"
```

It did not give any error on the console, but when I checked Solr logs it was throwing error.

```
ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/alfresco/error/AlfrescoRuntimeException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

This was because I was running JDK on the machine whereas Alfresco Search Services 1.4 requires JDK 11. After upgrading to JDK 11 both core and archive got created and I was able to run queries again in the Node Browser.